# Why does MySQL uses only 0.5% Memory for every query?

Tags: mysql, memory, configuration

Why does MySQL uses only 0.5% Memory of 4 available GBs for every query on a huge table containing many joins and millions of rows? Is this an indicator for a false configured MySQL-Server?

Comment: Do you think that's lots, or not very much?

Comment: @Rich: I suspect MySQL has to use more memory, because the query is a complicated one.

Comment: I think he's thinking that it could use more to be faster and is wondering if he has something set incorrectly.

Comment: @Mike: That's it. =) In fact I am looking for a bottle neck in my system and I narrowed it down to the interaction with the MySQL-Server OR the processes that the MySQL server executes. But I am no expert at configuring the MySQL Server so I am asking for some help in how to detect possible errors in the configuration.

Comment: Try increasing the various cache settings (`show variables like '%cache%'` to list them) and see if memory usage and/or performance changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. There were two indices missing. The performance is good now. It still uses only 0.5% of memory in average and that's fine with me! =)